# How to bring caption (with transperancy) into an image in r markdown

Tags: r, image, r-markdown, caption, figcaption

I try to make a basic structure file in r markdown where I can show 2 images.
How can I bring the caption with transperancy into the image.
And can someone give me a tip how to present a r markdown code as a question? The 3 backticks are working until the next ``` ..., and this is a problem with bunch of code junks. Thank you.

output:

[image].

desired output:

[image]

code:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "TJ"
date: "7 1 2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

```
## R Markdown

![](output.png) 


## desired Output with caption in images

![](desired_output.png)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `image_read`and `image_annotate` from the package `magick`. Here is an example:

```
library(magick)
yoda <-image_read(path = "yoda.jpg")

    
image_annotate(
  yoda,
  "Figure 1A",
  size = 30,
  color = "white",
  boxcolor = adjustcolor("black", alpha = 0.2), #change the alpha value for more of less transparency
  gravity = "southwest"
)
```

[image]

If you want to specify the location of the caption you can replace `gravity = "southwest"` with with `location = " your cordinates"`. Ex:

```
image_annotate(
  yoda,
  "Figure 1A",
  size = 30,
  color = "white",
  boxcolor = adjustcolor("black", alpha = 0.2), #change the alpha value for more of less transparency
  location = "+10+400"
)
```

[image]

More about the [magick package here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html).

About the second question about write Markdown as code in the text:
Select the text you want as a code and press `tab` twice:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I just answered your second question that I had missed.